# Bootstrap Split button dropdown size not same

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

(Sorry, I'm not good at English)

[image: Image of Button's dropdown icon not aligning]

I want to make button same size. But It was not same size.

How I can make its size same?

```
<div class="filter pull-right" style="padding:8px">
<!-- Split button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: can you post the code you are using, what you have tried, and what you would like to see. thanks!

Comment: Please show the code that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Use `btn-group` class

```
<div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                &nbsp;
                <span class="caret"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: some thing disturbing `btn btn-danger` , i added one space it will work

Comment: Thank you. However, this does not seem to be a fundamental solution.. Anyway, Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is actually not related to the code of the button or a missing space.

What is missing is the HTML tag in the beginning of the document.

Here, you see the button on the left without additional `&nbsp;` and with additional `&nbsp;` on the right. The button on the right is somewhat non-symmetric.

[image: no html tag]

Following the [Boostrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-doctype) adding this code around your document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  ...
</html>
```

You will end up with a button like this:
[image: with html tag]